# How to do the unit testing on stm32 programming

Tags: stm32

I have STM 32 nucleo board .I have done a program for an embedded functionality. Currently I want to do the unit testing for the functionalities including the peripherals like ADC,SPI,UART..Can anyone suggest the Unit testing framework to test the functionality for the same.

Comment: it will be difficult. Unfortunately many of the large computer axioms are not good when you work with the uCs

Answer (score 4):

There are two common strategies that I'm aware of:

1. Make sure you have a good SW component architecture, including a well-defined interface towards HAL/driver components that only take care of access to HW port registers.
   Devise a separate verification method for low-level HW-access components, which avoids unit-testing tooling.
   To establish such a verification concept, make sure

   - to avoid any processing logic in HAL/driver components as far as possible.
   - to avoid any HW dependencies and any non-portable code in the remaining parts of your SW.

   Now you can take the HW-free parts of your code to some PC architecture (x86 or whatever) and do all your unit testing with conventional UT tools.
   Of course, your UT will miss any errors that are related to the differences between STM32 and your PC.
   Note that usually this is not too big a problem because HW-specific features have been "pushed" into the HAL, and in the other parts of the code, you are only looking for logical errors that have nothing to do with the HW/architecture.

   I know that this part of the answer talks round your subject instead of providing the solution you were asking for.
   Nevertheless, this is what many projects do.
2. (Develop yourself an STM32 integration for your unit-testing framework, or) buy a commercial unit-testing tool that supports your HW architecture.
   STM32 is very popular nowadays, so many commercial tools (Tessy, VectorCast etc.) provide integration that may fit your system.
   Note that you also have to select your build toolchain (and possibly the debug adapter) in line with this tool selection, so you have to check some additional constraints.

To get some orientation for your decision between those two strategies, you should consider the question which purpose you are carrying out the unit testing for:

- Which kinds of errors are you going to find this way? Which other verification methods are you already applying? Which robustness does your application have to achieve/guarantee - how critical is your application?

  *Usually, a certain kind/level of criticality corresponds to a certain amount of efforts in order to reduce the probability of residual errors in your software/system as low as reasonably practicable ([ALARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALARP)). You should make sure to "spend" those efforts in a balanced way so that you find as many errors as possible with every added verification. Unit-testing of low-level code is more tedious and often finds less mistakes (per test case or per working hour) than other sorts of testing.*
- Do you have to prove a certain level of UT coverage in order to fulfill process criteria like safety standars (e. g., IEC 61508-3 and derived standards), internal company standards, etc.?
  Then you have to check what those standards demand for your application, and discuss your strategy with the corresponding assessors.

  *If such requirements apply to your situation, you will have to convince the assessors that the verification measures applied are sufficient. For professional efficiency, it is crucial that you make up your mind (and start the discussion) which strategy to follow at the beginning of the project.*

---

**Edit**: I just came across [a good discussion of this topic at SoftwareEngineeringStackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104332/best-practice-when-unit-testing-for-embedded-development).
Have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Unity](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity) the test framework is just a few header files to add to the project. You can augment this with Cmock and Ceedling to build your unit tests on a host machine. You can also use platformio to gather integration test results as shown [here](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/tutorials/ststm32/stm32cube_debugging_unit_testing.html#tutorial-stm32cube-debugging-unit-testing). I have not yet figured out if Cmock works on an stm32 board but I may try in the near future.

I have unit tested STM32 code with cmock and ceedling (on Linux) and then some integration tests on target.